# SpringBoot with JPA in IntelliJ

Tags: spring, maven, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm just starting with Spring, and actually I'm step by step tutorial so everything would work well, but somehow I've got problem with running spring boot after adding JPA elements.

Earlier I had problem with Database type NONE, so I manually added depedency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.12.1.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

But I feel that still something is missing in pom file which looks like this:
[Pom.XML](http://pastebin.com/V8GAajjZ)

Consol output with an error looks like this:
[Console output](http://pastebin.com/TbjU6GPL)

Implementation:
1.
[class Topic](http://pastebin.com/Qdy4pbaf)
2.
[class TopicController](http://pastebin.com/7cBJcSgv)
3.
[class TopicRepository](http://pastebin.com/z1pdAtuZ)
4.
[class: TopicService](http://pastebin.com/Tb0xbVkA)
5.
[run class](http://pastebin.com/FaxhyvGy)

Comment: Post the error stack trace, as well as the relevant code, in the question. Hibernate clearly complains about the class Topic not being a managed type. Post this class, and your hibernate/jpa configuration.

Comment: You console output says your topicRepository class cannot be initialized due to class defaultpackage.topic.Topic, which seems to be your bean. Can you share details on the implementation?

Comment: added full code

Comment: You need to add entity annotation on Topic class so CrudRepository can work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to annotate Topic class:

```
package defaultpackage.topic;

/**
 * Created by zales on 02.03.2017.
 */
@Entity
public class Topic {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String discription;


    public Topic() {
    }

    public Topic(String id, String name, String discription) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.discription = discription;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDiscription() {
        return discription;
    }

    public void setDiscription(String discription) {
        this.discription = discription;
    }
}
```

You can see a similar sample with Entities and Repositories in here:

https://github.com/ccoloradoc/HibernateFilePermissionSample

Also make sure all your entities are in same package(or subpackage) as your SpringBootApplication.

Comment: everything work to me, thanks! I had only to delete @GeneratedValue, because I'm not using casual IDs like 1,2,3 and Ids are Strings